# How to get http server response in case of 401 using wget?

Tags: wget, http

I need to test my http server responses in various cases, even for failed authentication. In case of failed authentication, my server returns `401 Unauthorized` and also a response body which simple contains `Unauthorized` (or maybe some other detailed message).

Using e.g. `curl` or `httpie`, I got those response body in case of `401` response.

```
$ curl http://10.5.1.1/bla 
Unauthorized
$ curl http://10.5.1.1/bla --digest --user joe:wrong 
Unauthorized
$ http http://10.5.1.1/bla -b
Unauthorized
$ http http://10.5.1.1/bla -b --auth-type digest --auth joe:wrong
Unauthorized
```

But when trying this using wget, I got no output:

```
$ wget http://10.5.1.1/bla -q -O /dev/stdout
$ wget http://10.5.1.1/bla -q -O /dev/stdout --user joe --password wrong
```

wget returns with exitcode 6 in this case, but I need to check the response message.

Here is a dump of the complete traffic, captured using httpie:

```
$ http http://10.5.1.1/bla --print hbHB
GET /bla HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.5.1.1
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: 2017-08-27 23:01:07
Server: Vistra-I St10 SW218 HW010
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Vistra-I", qop="auth", nonce="a0c5d461f2b74b2b797b62f54200d125", opaque="0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"

Unauthorized
```

(Note that the `Unauthorized` message in the response body ends with a new line character, that's why Content-Length: 13)

Same thing, if the server respond with `403` or `404` et cetera.
Any idea how to get the response body using `wget` in this case?

**Edit 2017-09-22**

Found `--content-on-error` option in my wget 1.17.1 (see also [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content-On-Error)).

This works in case of e.g. response code `404` but not for `401` nor `5xx` codes.

For `401` see [this bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2015-04/msg00093.html).

Answer (score 8):

I was able to obtain server response in case of `404`, `503` errors with `wget 1.20.1` with the following command:

`wget --no-verbose --save-headers --content-on-error=on --timeout=3 --tries=1 -O- http://127.0.0.1:8080/bla`

Example output:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Endpoint-Path: GET /bla
X-Sub-Calls-Count: 0
X-Mdc: XNIO-1 task-11550846786294
X-Child-Calls-Count: 0
X-Hop: 1
Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2019 14:46:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

{"id":"266a8c43-81ae-4b73-bb0c-d3e0a37a11c4","createdAt":1550846786327,"httpCode":404,"code":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://127.0.0.1:8080/bla"}http://127.0.0.1:8080/bla:
2019-02-22 15:46:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Doesn't work in BusyBox v1.29.3: `wget: unrecognized option: content-on-error=on`

Comment: Yes, it works for `400`.  But how to see the content on redirect `302`?

Comment: Works also for 410. content-on-error=on does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Response header can be retrieved using the following `wget` option

```
wget --server-response http://10.5.1.1/bla
```

I'm not aware of any optino that will allow you to retrieve the response body when an error happens using `wget`

In case you want the response body with another command, use `curl` as is:

```
curl http://10.5.1.1/bla
```

Comment: This gives me the response header but not the response body

Comment: What about `curl http://10.5.1.1/bla` ?

Comment: Yes, it works with both curl and httpie, but I want to make it also work with wget (if possible).

Comment: Not sure you can with wget

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with "403  Forbidden" I have to use `--content-on-error` as the other answers say, but for some reason I only see the error message if I also use `-q`. So the trick is using both:

```
wget -q --content-on-error -O- http://...
```